actions/setup-java@v3 throwing error "Trying to resolve the latest version from remote Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.adoptium.net"
New to GitHub Actions, trying to set the pull request analysis with SONARQUBE.
getting error-

Trying to resolve the latest version from remote Error: getaddrinfo
ENOTFOUND api.adoptium.net"

script :
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 #comment
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17.0.6'
          distribution: 'temurin'
      - name: Cache SonarQube packages
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.sonar/cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-sonar
      - name: Cache Gradle packages
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.gradle/caches
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle
      - name: Build and analyze
        env:
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_HOST_URL: ${{ secrets.SONAR_HOST_URL }}
        run: ./gradlew build sonar --info

tried we all v1,v2,v3,v4 for set-up java action, though its failing with same error and warning

"Build
Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. Please update the following
actions to use Node.js 16: actions/checkout@v2. For more information
see:
https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/.

error and warning image
Any solution or missing step in this flow ?

You run the workflow on a self-hosted runner and it seems it could not resolve the host name under api.adoptium.net. Please verify if you can resolve the name using additional debug step like - run: curl -LI api.adoptium.net. This should give you a hint.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
